# How to set topmost big contact entry in contact in iPhone 5C?

Tags: iphone, contacts

When I open Contacts app in iPhone 5c, I see one contact displayed on the top of the list with bigger font and icon.

How to choose this entry?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The contact displayed on top of the list with bigger font and icon is generally your own contact entry, i.e. the contact entry corresponding to logged in Apple ID.</strike>

You can tap to select and navigate to the details screen and edit the fields in the detail screen.

**Update**: As mentioned by @fsb in comment, Go to Settings app → Contacts and verify the contact selected for My Info is actually your own contact card. That's where Contacts app gets the name for the top of the list entry.

Comment: In my case it shows not myself. If I edit it, I edit some person't contact info.

Comment: What is the version of iOS installed on your iPhone? Try logging out you Apple ID and logging back in from within the Settings app.

Comment: Go to `Settings -> Contacts` and verify the contact selected for `My Info` is actually your contact card.  That's where Contacts gets the name for the top of the list.